# Flash Builder network monitor not recording file uploads?

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-builder

I'm uploading an image file with upload() of a FileReference object however the network monitor in Flash Builder doesn't report anything. Is that normal behavior? A google search didn't return anything.

Comment: Do you load your file from the disk and not via the network? Then the network monitor won't show network traffic. I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a Flex project or an pure Actionscript project? The Network Monitor does not support applications that were created using pure ActionScript and Library projects.

**Be aware of the following limitations when monitoring network data:**

- The Network Monitor **does not support** applications that were created using pure ActionScript and Library projects.
- The Network Monitor does not support the Real Time Messaging Protocol (RTMP). For example, you cannot monitor streaming video.